# Reading text file and sorting two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, readfile

I have a "Temp.dat" with 200 lines that looks like this:

```
0.060493 1 0.5 1
1.596961 0 0.1 2
0.87758  1 0.3 1.5
0.165453 1 0   3
0.07085  1 0.3 4
0.125379 1 0.2 3
0.454202 1 0.2 2
0.373227 1 0.3 1
0.131486 1 0.3 3
0.867477 0 0.5 4
0.122609 0 0.8 9
```

I am trying to read each line and store each column of data into separate arrays with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 200

int main(){

  double x[MAX], y[MAX];
  double a, b;
  int m = 0;
  FILE* file; 
  file = fopen("Temp.dat", "r");
  if ( file != NULL ){
      /* Read the two columns. */
      while(fscanf(file, "%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
      { x[m] = a;
        y[m] = b;
        m++;
      }
  }
  printf("%d %d\n", x[4], y[1]); # Test the stored inputs of the two arrays
  return(0);
}
```

When I tried printing out the result, it gave `1 13258992`, rather than `0.165453 0`. I cannot understand where it got the pair `1 13258992`, as I thought the line `fscanf(file, "%d %d", &a, &b) == 2` did what it's supposed to do: go through each row of the file `Temp.dat` and read the two `double-type` integers, then stored in the two arrays `x[MAX]` and `y[MAX]. Therefore, could anyone please help me fix this issue?

Another question: After storing the two columns above in two arrays `x[MAX]` and `y[MAX]`, I would like to sort the two arrays in an increasing order based on the values in the first array `x[MAX]`. This would look like:

```
    0.060493 1
    0.07085  1
    0.122609 0
    0.125379 1
    0.131486 1
    0.165453 1
    0.373227 1
    0.454202 1
    0.867477 0
```

How could I do this `sorting` routine in C, as it's quite hard to arrange the elements in `y[MAX]` to follow the order of their corresponding elements in `x[MAX]`?

Comment: @Pablo: Thank you for your help. I added the condition in the `while`, and change `%d` to `%lf`, but the result is still incorrect. Now it gave me `-1 34902256` for the same `x[4] y[1]`. Could you give me some hints on how to sort the second array while I am swapping each element of the first array?

Comment: I removed my comment and posted it as an answer. You had the same error in the `printf` call. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a structure with `x` and `y`, so that the two values are  tied together, `x` and `y` will keep their relation when array elements are swapped during sort. Example:

```
struct data_t
{
    double x;
    int y;
};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct data_t *m = a;
    const struct data_t *n = b;
    if(m->x == n->x)
        return m->y > n->y;
    return m->x > n->x;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct data_t data[MAX];
    FILE* file = fopen("Temp.dat", "r");
    int count = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%lf %d", &data[count].x, &data[count].y) == 2)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == MAX)
            break;
    }

    qsort(data, count, sizeof(struct data_t), compare);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%lf %d\n", data[i].x, data[i].y);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Use `%lf` for `double` values, or use `%f` for `float` , as shown in the other answers</sup>

About the compare function, lets say you have these values in your data:

```
0.060493 1
0.060493 5
0.060493 2
```

In this case the `x` value from first element is same as `x` value from the other element. If you only test for `m->x > n->x` then sorting does not occur. So you want to compare `m->y > n->y` if `x` is the same.

`qsort` is a standard C function. It doesn't know your data type, we have to have to tell it about the data type. That's done inside the compare function which receives pointers `a` and `b`, we know these are pointers to elements in `data` array, so that's reason behind the conversion.

The data set can contain up to `200` items since we declared it as `struct data_t data[MAX];` where `MAX` is `200`.

---

Edit 3 ******

---

Working with arrays, declare the array:

`double arr[MAX + 1][8]`

Note that the first index of the array is rows from `0` to `MAX`. It's set up this way so it can be sorted later. Now we can read the file directly in to the array, and sort the array (no need for structure). Make sure you don't mix this up with the old solutions which had `arr[8][MAX + 1]`

```
int compare_2d_array(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    double a = *(double*)pa;
    double b = *(double*)pb;
    return a > b;
}

int main(void)
{
    //array with MAX + 1 rows, and 8 columns, initialized to zero
    double arr[MAX + 1][8] = { 0 };
    FILE* file = fopen("temp.dat", "r");
    int count = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%lf %lf", &arr[count][0], &arr[count][1]) == 2)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == MAX) break;
    }

    qsort(arr, count, sizeof(arr[0]), compare_2d_array);

    //arr[0] and arr[1] are ready, now set up the other columns:
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //make modifications to other columns
        arr[i][2] = i ? arr[i - 1][0] : 0;
        arr[i][3] = arr[i][0];
        arr[i + 1][4] = i + 1;

        printf("%.6lf %.0lf %.6lf %.6lf %.0lf\n", 
                    arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2], arr[i][3], arr[i][4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried out your code and it works fantastically with the dataset!! Many thanks for your help. I have some questions though: could you help explain to me why the return `m->y > n->y`? in your `compare()` function? Also, the declaration of a pointer `const struct data_t *m = a` helps on?? Is `struct data_t` = a dataset with $200$ pairs of `(x,y)`?

Comment: Many thanks for your help, as it's quite clear!! I have another question: from the two columns, assume the first denotes the time $T$, and the second means `1= Death occurs` and `0 = Censor occurs`. I want to create two arrays, which store the following computed quantity: first array stores number of people that are *alive* and *not* censored between any two *successive* time periods, and second array stores number of death occurs during the *same* time periods. May you help assist on how i am supposed to do this with `int array[MAX]` and `for` loop?

Comment: I tried `for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){sum[i] = MAX - i;}` but then `printf("%d", &sum[4])` outputs nothing for me. Not quite sure why it is not stored in the array `sum[]`? Also, I want to store the first column into an array where each element = successive time periods whose endpoints correspond to `1` in the second column (so, no endpoint would correspond to `0`). But I am stumbled at how to write such a complex condition like this. Could you give some help?

Comment: I tried that `printf("%d", sum[4])` too, but it still does not print anything (although no error messages occurs). Anyway, could you please help show me how to store successive time periods in an array that have endpoints both equal to `1` in the 2nd column? For example, an array with elements `[0, 0.060493), [0.060493, 0.07085), [0.07085, 0.122609)`, etc. I think I might have to use 2-dimensional array, one of which is to store the time period, the other is to store computational results, and the index of these two match exactly (i.e, for `t\in [0, 0.060493)`, we have `result 1`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165392/discussion-between-user177196-and-barmak-shemirani).

Comment: Look at (Edit 3 ****), include that in your new question along with input sample and the expected output

Comment: if I add two additional columns into the original dataset, do you know how to arrange the elements in those two columns based on the sorting result of the first column?? Does your function `compare()`, but with 2 additional pointers in the input setting, still work (i.e,` int compare(const void *a, const void *b, const void *c, const void *d)`)?

Comment: could you please help me with my question in the comment above? I modified the original dataset for clarity. I tried writing the `int compare_4d_array(const void *a, const void *b, const void *c, const void *d)`, but it fails to work out properly.

Comment: I don't mean to sort anything else, except to change the corresponding rows of entries in columns 2 and 3 above to the correct ones after sorting based on columns 0 and 1 above, as you presented. But I would start a new question then.

Comment: I got confused. My previous comment doesn't make sense. You still have **one** 2-d array. There is no 4-d array. Keep the function proc as `compare_2d_array(const void *element1, const void *element2)`

Comment: You can ask a new question based on "sorting 2-d array, based on 2 or more columns". Also, in another question I showed how to sort a structure, that was a similar concept.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Could you kindly share the link to that question with me?

Comment: I posted the new one! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183054/sorting-2-d-array-based-on-the-first-column. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First add `&& m < MAX` in the `while` conditions, so that you don't overflow the buffer.

`scanf` expects with `%d` a pointer to `int`, not to `double` and it will parse the content as an integer.
You have to use `%lf` to parse `double`s. The same applies to the `printf` call:

```
while(fscanf(file, "%lf %lf", &a, &b) == 2 && m < MAX)
    ...

...

printf("%lf %lf\n", x[4], y[1]);
```

I get

```
0.070850 0.000000
```

which is the fifth line of you dat file (not the fourth, array indices start by 0, not 1).

As for your other question:

I'm afraid you have to write your own sort function.

Comment: I got the first part now!! Thanks a ton for your help, Pablo. I am using Mac's OS. Could you please help show me how to do this with `qsort_r`?

Comment: Like I said, `qsort_r` is a GNU extension of the GCC compiler, you would need to compile it with the GCC compiler. Sorry to confuse you, but even `qsort_r` would not help here, because you need to know which indices in the array are being compared and `qsort` passes the values, not the indices. I'm afraid you would have to write your own sorting function.

Answer (score 1):

For starters try:

```
double a;
int b;

...

fscanf(file, "%f %d", &a, &b)
```

You initialized `a` and `b` as double type but you are reading integers (`%d`) from the copy.dat file.  `b` is an int value so leave `%d` in the `fscanf` and change the initialization.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a ton. Could you help with the sort function?

Comment: Do a search for a bubble sort. It’s not the most efficient or prettiest sort but it is easy to code and it will work through 200 values basically instantly.

Comment: To get the y array to follow the sort of the x array apply the search logic to the x array only but swap both the x and y array at the same time.