# sorting 2-d array based on the first column

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I have a `temp2.dat` file that looks like this:

```
0.060493 1 0.5 1
1.596961 0 0.1 2
0.87758  1 0.3 1.5
0.165453 1 0   3
0.07085  1 0.3 4
0.125379 1 0.2 3
0.454202 1 0.2 2
0.373227 1 0.3 1
0.131486 1 0.3 3
0.867477 0 0.5 4
0.122609 0 0.8 9
```

Now I want to write the function in `C` to sort these 4 columns in an increasing order but only based on the values of the first column. I tried modifying the following code but it failed:

```
struct data_t
{
    double x;
    int y;
    double z;
    double k;
};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct data_t *m = a;
    const struct data_t *n = b;
    if(m->x == n->x)
        return m->y > n->y;
        return m->z > n->z;
        return m->k > n->k;
    return m->x > n->x;
}
```

Could someone please help me do this? The expected result should look like this:

```
0.060493 1 0.5 1
0.07085  1 0.3 4
0.122609 0 0.8 9
0.125379 1 0.2 3
0.131486 1 0.3 3
................
0.87758  1 0.3 1.5
1.596961 0 0.1 2
```

Comment: Your `compare` function is bizarre. Please look up some examples of, presumably, `qsort`, and be wary of testing floating point values for equality. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: `return m->k > n->k;` and `return m->x > n->x;` are useless, they will never be reached, you can only return 1 object from a function. And I highly recommend adding some brackets `{ ... }` to your `if` statement to make it clear with you want, or at least changing the indentation. What you have now is misleading.

Comment: @yano: thank you so much. I would note this point next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this compare function

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct data_t *m = a;
    const struct data_t *n = b;

    if(m->x != n->x)
        return (m->x > n->x) - (m->x < n->x);

    if(m->y != n->y)
        return m->y - n->y;

    if(m->z != n->z)
        return (m->z > n->z) - (m->z < n->z);

    if(m->k != n->k)
        return (m->k > n->k) - (m->x < n->k);

    return 0;
}
```

This will compare the first column `x`. If `x` is the same in the two elements, it moves to the second column `y`. If the second column is the same, it moves to the third column and so on.

We want the difference between the two values. Example, `m->y - n->y`. The compare function should return an integer value 0, negative, or positive.

When comparing `double` values, we cannot use `m->x - n->x`, because the return value for `compare` is `int`. We use a comparison function instead.

Testing

```
struct data_t
{
    double x;
    int y;
    double z;
    double k;
};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct data_t *m = a;
    const struct data_t *n = b;

    if(m->x != n->x)
        return (m->x > n->x) ? 1 : -1;

    if(m->y != n->y)
        return m->y - n->y;

    if(m->z != n->z)
        return (m->z > n->z) ? 1 : -1;

    if(m->k != n->k)
        return (m->k > n->k) ? 1 : -1;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct data_t data[] = 
    { 
        { 0.060493, 3, 0.4, 7 },//1st column is the same
        { 0.060493, 2, 0.5, 8 },
        { 0.060493, 1, 0.6, 9 },

        { 0.060493, 3, 0.3, 4 },//1st & 2nd columns are the same
        { 0.060493, 3, 0.2, 5 },
        { 0.060493, 3, 0.1, 6 },

        { 0.060493, 1, 0.5, 3 },//1st & 2nd & 3rd columns are the same
        { 0.060493, 1, 0.5, 2 },
        { 0.060493, 1, 0.5, 1 },

        { 0.122609, 0, 0.8, 9 },
        { 0.125379, 1, 0.2, 3 },
        { 0.131486, 1, 0.3, 3 },
    };

    int count = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    qsort(data, count, sizeof(data[0]), compare);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%.6f %d %.1f %.0f\n",
            data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].z, data[i].k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> 0.060493 1 0.5 1
> 0.060493 1 0.5 2
> 0.060493 1 0.5 3
> 0.060493 1 0.6 9
> 0.060493 2 0.5 8
> 0.060493 3 0.1 6
> 0.060493 3 0.2 5
> 0.060493 3 0.3 4
> 0.060493 3 0.4 7
> 0.122609 0 0.8 9
> 0.125379 1 0.2 3
> 0.131486 1 0.3 3
> ```

Comment: Many thanks for your great help! If the first column is not the same, each time your `compare()` function would automatically shift the elements in the same row but in remaining columns, down 1 row?

Comment: I printed the output, it looks right. It's sorting the 1st column, then 2nd column etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in C if you want more than one statement inside any block, you have to surround it with `{` and `}`. So your last 3 `return` statements would never be reached (the indentation does not matter for the compiler, only for humans).

Second, when you call `return`, your code does not come back. So you could use nested `if`s to compare the values in case they are the same in some of the columns. Something like:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct data_t *m = a;
    const struct data_t *n = b;
    if(m->x == n->x) {
        if (m->y == n->y) {
            if (m->z == n->z) {
                return m->k > n->k;
            }
            return m->z > n->z;
        }
        return m->y > n->y;
    }
    return m->x > n->x;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the correct logic is to subtract, not to compare

Comment: Ah, I missed the qsort tag. Just inferred what the compare function did from what OP wrote.

Comment: @BrunoEly: Thank you so much! Let me try your code to see if it actually does what I want to. Did you try it with the given sample dataset above?

Comment: Note: This `compare()` is sufficient to use with `qsort()` as that expects negative return values too.